# My Github application is holding onto deleted files

Tags: github

I already deleted this .gitignore file from my harddrive but the github for windows application still includes it in commits. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

explorer view of my website
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OxM8.png

github client view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq2YB.png

Cheers,
Thomas N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine works when I use `git rm .gitignore`. If you just used Windows Explorer to delete it, then Git still has that file in it's list of files to be committed and checked for changes. RM removes it from this list.